# bokeh align controls vertically

Tags: bokeh

I am using Bokeh to add a button and a slider to a row as follows:

```
self.slider =  Slider(start=0, end=588, value=0, step=1, title="")
self.slider.show_value = False
self.button = Button(label='❚❚', width=40)
self.layout = row(self.button, row(self.slider, sizing_mode='scale_width'))
```

Now, when I add it  to my plot, it looks something like this:

[image]

How can I make the slider and the buttons align at their vertical centers. It seems by default  the vertical top is aligned but not sure how I can align vertical centers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to position widgets exactly in the middle but you could shift them using `spacing`:

```
self.layout = column(Div(), row(self.button, self.slider), spacing=200)
```